# RestTemplate exchange call with POST method

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using `RestTemplate` to consume Spring REST service. Spring REST service having method type as `POST` also having query parameter,

**e.g.**: `http://example.com/help?requestString={{"q1":"a1"}}`

When I tried to consume the above endpoint using `restTemplate.exchange(url,post,httpentity)`, it did not work because curly braces not allowed in URL. But when encode my query parameter (requestString) value and do the `restTemplate.exchange(...)` it works fine.

But I am facing issue at end point side, I do not have any rights to change the code of the end point.

The issue is: When I call `restTemplate.exchange(...)` with encoded value, the end point function is not able to decode `request.getParameter("requestString")` value.

So is there any setting/configuration in `RestTemplate` to send encoded query parameter to end point and end point will get decoded format of data?

Comment: You want to have the json in request body not in the url.

Comment: @SiHa  I want to send that json with URL as query parameter. To perform this, I have encoded json query parameter. But at end point side it is not going to be docoded that parameter.